# Run-time error '2465' ...can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression

Tags: vba, runtime

I keep getting the message `Run-time error '2465' ...can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression` and I have no idea where to find the cause, please help!

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "JournalDetailsDrilldown", acNormal, , "SQL_Where" And [Plymouth - Nominal Detail]![Client Ref] = " & Forms!MainMenu![Client Ref] & "
```

the one below is working now
    DoCmd.OpenForm "JournalDetailsDrilldown", acNormal, ,SQL_Where & " And [Client Ref] = " & Forms!MainMenu![Client Ref]

error message sorted, many thanks to Jacouh!!1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SQL_Where = "[Date]>=#" & Format([Forms]![MainMenu]![StartDate], "mm/dd/yyyy") _
  & "# AND [Date]<=#" & Format([Forms]![MainMenu]![EndDate], "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
DoCmd.OpenForm "JournalDetailsDrilldown", acNormal, , SQL_Where & " And [Client Ref] = " & Forms!MainMenu![Client Ref]
```

SQL_Where can be replaced by suitable SQL where string in form of

```
Columnname = "ColumnValue"
```

For a string filed in the table [Plymouth - Nominal Detail]. Or:

```
Columnname = ColumnValue
```

if [Plymouth - Nominal Detail]!Columnname is of type numeric.